# Unable to authorize using Google api client to access Hangout chat api

Tags: java, google-api, google-oauth, google-authentication, google-api-java-client

I am using google.api.client version 1.30.9 . I want to authenticate my requests  using Hangout Chat Api before sending . In the official doc https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/oauth2 google has used GoogleCredential but it has now been deprecated. I am using the following code to get the authenticated credential object that can be used to build HangoutChat object.

```
private static Credential authorize() throws Exception {
        httpTransport=GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
        dataStoreFactory = new FileDataStoreFactory(DATA_STORE_DIR);
        // load client secrets
        GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY,
                new InputStreamReader(HangoutsChat.class.getResourceAsStream("/client_secrets.json")));
        // set up authorization code flow
        GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
                httpTransport, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets,
                Collections.singleton(HangoutsChat.DEFAULT_BASE_URL)).setDataStoreFactory(dataStoreFactory)
                .build();
        // authorize
        return new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, new LocalServerReceiver()).authorize("user");

    }
```

AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp and LocalServerReceiver and are not available in the latest version of google API . How can I authenticate before requesting using hangout chat API.

Comment: What makes you think that credentials have been deprecated?

Comment: I found that out from the documentation of GoogleCredential https://googleapis.dev/java/google-api-client/latest/com/google/api/client/googleapis/auth/oauth2/GoogleCredential.html.

Answer (score 1):

You state that you are trying to use a service account but the code you are using was designed fora web application to login using Oauth2 this will notwork with service account credentials you must use the proper code with the corect type of credentials.

[service account](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/oauth2#service_accounts)

```
HttpTransport httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
JsonFactory jsonFactory = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
...
// Build service account credential.

GoogleCredential credential = GoogleCredential.fromStream(new FileInputStream("MyProject-1234.json"))
    .createScoped(Collections.singleton(PlusScopes.PLUS_ME));
// Set up global Plus instance.
plus = new Plus.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, credential)
    .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME).build();
...
```

## Explicit Credential Loading

[Google auth libray](https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-java/blob/master/README.md)

To get Credentials from a Service Account JSON key use GoogleCredentials.fromStream(InputStream) or GoogleCredentials.fromStream(InputStream, HttpTransportFactory). Note that the credentials must be refreshed before the access token is available.

```
GoogleCredentials credentials = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(new FileInputStream("/path/to/credentials.json"));
credentials.refreshIfExpired();
AccessToken token = credentials.getAccessToken();
// OR
AccessToken token = credentials.refreshAccessToken();
```

Comment: I moved from this approach to the one mentioned in question. Using this approach I was only able to find this sample which used GoogleCredential which has been deprecated, I would prefer to authenticate using my service account only if I am to bypass this problem .

Comment: Oauth2 is not the same as service account authentication.  The library it self has a readme which shows how to authenticate using a service account  https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-java/blob/master/README.md

Comment: Thanks I did not come across this doc . But isn't service account authentication a sub type of oauth2?